# Cannot assign UUID to bash variable

Tags: bash, uuid, aws-batch

I want to script termination of jobs on AWS Batch and I am running into problems while assigning UUIDs to bash variables.

I have a text file named 'LastAndFinal_job_id_list.txt with two columns as follows:

```
cbac858b-3884-41c7-8bb7-97eeca8339ae    LastAndFinal12
12c2085c-c62b-4c89-8afc-e9448c792a85    LastAndFinal9
a4698208-dd5c-4e1f-bc14-5f8ebc6aadb4    LastAndFinal4
aa601bed-ee86-49ff-b508-eb488d560e42    LastAndFinal33
2cf8739a-5600-454b-a056-8e6c65762b4b    LastAndFinal1
b93375cc-3ec7-48e4-833c-146c81cf8aca    LastAndFinal10
bf7bfbe7-bb73-4f88-8098-a1e48844f384    LastAndFinal31
86bec3d7-7608-46a5-8d9d-77a57b91807f    LastAndFinal28
31f077d9-c658-4d61-8d25-c75d56d26adc    LastAndFinal27
dbb29c3b-f63d-4f1f-9f10-e3b1267cda04    LastAndFinal17
5a9fb315-82b2-4750-97c1-cbc47a57dd3b    LastAndFinal15
a5a36434-c051-42ff-a08d-cbc397985341    LastAndFinal2
9e2ad835-296e-4bc1-9ea0-72272ac27217    LastAndFinal23
0e128231-de69-4101-b726-f125f424f651    LastAndFinal7
9c984064-2a9e-4f3d-908f-07f50c6ef9a9    LastAndFinal25
3265913e-f846-47a4-8e0d-c467bf65cce3    LastAndFinal20
97846185-ea06-4f4a-8377-1e56640f9099    LastAndFinal22
a28857ac-386f-4efe-ab5d-d3d0e7b862c9    LastAndFinal24
4330edd3-84f9-434a-9929-0805629ab8b9    LastAndFinal8
565f1ac3-3b56-4b14-8a67-398afca98d7c    LastAndFinal5
a5179933-4805-4a61-9e1e-73ed1c9f9689    LastAndFinal21
b9d76d04-3e78-4db9-8fb0-e79f5477e672    LastAndFinal29
539a11d1-3c9b-4076-bce9-aa760d99887b    LastAndFinal13
19c06f4b-be90-4bfa-8263-6d4861259deb    LastAndFinal11
4889ba41-852a-419d-9f09-ee918c5a33e9    LastAndFinal19
8063adc4-7ea8-42f6-b5e2-7ed391c6278b    LastAndFinal16
c03e0feb-8be7-4bdc-83a4-0ca0bbc7a34b    LastAndFinal14
43ce685a-2764-4bd4-ab43-57f3647c7734    LastAndFinal3
f4b77e2f-0774-42aa-afd2-7c835c720e6c    LastAndFinal0
7a6cd4d3-b29a-4760-8d92-93d8d72cee8e    LastAndFinal6
a676a3d4-ade4-413e-859d-3bba0c5bb082    LastAndFinal30
0efc9ccb-f508-42e2-b3ef-daebc4bff227    LastAndFinal34
b0fffb70-d92f-45b8-acca-ce050d990fd8    LastAndFinal32
addcc063-6f3e-41a4-90c2-274cf117ec97    LastAndFinal18
6bd35938-b5f9-4dc9-8cd9-bcfa53b4f04e    LastAndFinal26
```

"LastAndFinal*" in the second column is a list of names of jobs that I submitted to AWS Batch and the UUIDs in the first column are corresponding Job IDs returned to me by AWS Batch.

I extract UUID for job with job name 'LastAndFinal22 by this command:

`job_id=$(cat LastAndFinal_job_id_list.txt | grep -w LastAndFinal22 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)`

Now the problem is when I echo `job_id`, I only get blank output. Any ideas to assign the UUID to the variable 'job_id'?

Comment: Just to avoid confusion: The OP's command _does_ work (but there are simpler alternatives, as shown in the answers) - they merely misspelled the variable name and mistakenly concluded that the variable was empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggested alternative using `awk`:

```
job_id=$(awk '$2 == "LastAndFinal22" { print $1 }' LastAndFinal_job_id_list.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`, you can get your `UUID` using backreference:

```
job_id=$(sed 's/\(^[^ ]* *\)LastAndFinal22.*/\1/' LastAndFinal_job_id_list.txt)
```

or using only `grep`:

```
job_id=$(grep -oP '[^ ]*(?= *LastAndFinal22)' LastAndFinal_job_id_list.txt)
```

Here, using the `-o`(only matching) flag, non space characters are output when followed by `*LastAndFinal22` in a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Oh this doesn't look neat...any idea why 'cutting' the ID doesn't work? Can you give a grep implementation?

Comment: I added a grep solution.